# Prove undecidability of a TM M that accepts at least one input AND rejects at least one input

Tags: turing-machines

I got stuck trying to prove that AND statement. I assumed that the TM will accept if its language is not empty and the complement of its language is not empty and reject if its language is empty or the complement of its language is empty. I tried reducing the Halting Problem but got stuck with proving that both the language and it complement are not empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I got stuck trying to prove that AND statement. I assumed that the TM will accept if its language is not empty and the complement of its language is not empty and reject if its language is empty or the complement of its language is empty. I tried reducing the Halting Problem but got stuck with proving that both the language and it complement are not empty

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, so—are you allowed to use Rice's Theorem? If so, this is a non-trivial semantic property.

Comment: Well, my professor said that this problem cannot be proven undecidable by Rice's Theorem...